# DAX/PowerBI Rank taking a variable/parameter into account

Tags: dax

I'm working on a ranking/scoring system and I'm missing the `PERCENTRANK.INC` function in powerBI. Instead I have worked out below formula which is the closest I can get.

```
Score =
DIVIDE (
    RANKX (
        FILTER ( 'Table', NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Sold amounts] ) ) ),
        [Sold amounts],
        ,
        ASC
    ) - 1,
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( 'Table', NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Sold amounts] ) ) ) ) - 1
)
```

I really want to have the formula to take the type of "Fruit" into account in my scoring/ranking.
In short each fruit should be scored separately, with a range per fruit sold.

Could this somehow be done with a variable (VAR)?

**Example of data:**

[image: Data example]

Comment: Can you post sample data in text format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.

```
Score = 
VAR fruit = 'Table'[Fruit]
VAR filteredTable = FILTER ( 'Table', NOT ( ISBLANK ( [Sold amount] ) ) && 'Table'[Fruit] = fruit)

RETURN
DIVIDE (
    RANKX (
        filteredTable,
        [Sold amount],
        ,
        ASC
    ) - 1,
    COUNTROWS ( filteredTable ) - 1
)
```

[image]

Comment: It does work, and very well! - only small thing. Sometimes there are blanks in sold amount which throws it off a bit.

Can I somehow work into the RETURN that is should return BLANK if Sold Amount is blank?